# How to tally data efficiently

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of grades and want to create a tally for the different grade intervals.
This works, but it seems tedious to type if there were more categories to test.

```
        for (int x: grades){
        if (x < 10) {
            tally[0] += 1;
        } else  if (x < 20) {
            tally[1] += 1;
        } else  if (x < 30) {
            tally[2] += 1;
        } else  if (x < 40) {
            tally[3] += 1;
        } else  if (x < 50) {
            tally[4] += 1;
        } else  if (x < 60) {
            tally[5] += 1;
        } else  if (x < 70) {
            tally[6] += 1;
        } else  if (x < 80) {
            tally[7] += 1;
        } else  if (x < 90) {
            tally[8] += 1;
        } else  if (x < 100) {
            tally[9] += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Do you see a pattern that would convert the range to an index?

Comment: But what if the ranges were not consistent intervals and were instead 0-9, 10-13, 14-19?

Comment: Look for a pattern. There might not be one.

Comment: You can use first value of your two digit number to score the array of X ++.. 11 store +1 to tally[1] if first dig is 4 store +1 to tally[4] if 1 dig.. tally[0] +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any intervals, pseudocode would be sort of

```
int intervals[11]={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90};
for(int i=1; i<11; i++)
{
    if(x>=intervals[i-1] && x<intervals[i])
        tally[i-1]+=1;
}
```

but if they're that simple(multiples of 10):

```
for(int i=1; i<11; i++)
{
    if(x>=(i-1)*10 && x<i*10) 
        tally[i-1]+=1;
}
```

@Edit
Or actually you could just:

```
int intervals[10]={10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90};
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    if(x<intervals[i])
        {tally[i]+=1; break;}
}
```

Comment: Crowed goes wiled this one is out of here... :P

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a pattern in the index and the grade value, we can easily calculate it using a single statement.
Try this:

```
    for (int x: grades){
        int y = x / 10;
        tally[y] += 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Guava's [`Range`s](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/RangesExplained) give a cool general solution here.

```
List<Range<Integer>> ranges = ImmutableList.of(
    Range.openClosed(0, 10),
    Range.openClosed(10, 20),
    // ...
);

RangeMap<Integer, AtomicInteger> counts = TreeRangeMap.create();

for (Range<Integer> range : ranges) {
   counts.put(range, new AtomicInteger(0));
}

for (int grade : grades) {
   counts.get(grade).increment();
}
```